# Cómo validar que el texto introducido en un input se encuentra entre una de las opciones de su Datalist

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
function iniciar() {
  lista = document.getElementById("personas");
  nombres = document.getElementById("nombre");
  correos = document.getElementById("correo");
  lista.addEventListener("input", validarNombre, false);
  nombres.addEventListener("input", validarNombre, false);
  correos.addEventListener("input", validarCorreo, false);
}

function validarNombre() {
  if (lista[0] !== nombres || lista[1] !== nombres || lista[2] !== nombres || lista[3] = !!nombres) alert("nombre no existente");
}

function validarCorreo() {
  if (!correos.endsWith(".es")) alert(El correo debe acabar en.es);
}
```

```html
<li>
  <datalist id="personas">
    <option value="alex" label="alex">
    <option value="juan" label="juan">
    <option value="ana" label="ana">
    <option value="Pedro" label="Pedro">
  </datalist>

  <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required placeholder="Escriba su nombre:" list="personas">
  <label> </label>
</li>
```

Necesito validar en JavaScript que el nombre que introduce el usuario exista en el `Datalist`, mostrando su mensaje por pantalla.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. ¿Podrías situar el código que has intentado hasta ahora y la pregunta concreta que deseas formular?

Comment: El codigo que he puesto anteriormente me funciona en html, y en javascript he probado a poner alert por si entra en alguna funcion

Comment: Me refiero a que sitúes el código `JavaScript` que has intentado y que no te funciona. Puedes consultar [cómo elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: function iniciar(){
  lista=document.getElementById("personas");
  nombres=document.getElementById("nombre")
  correos=document.getElementById("correo")
  lista.addEventListener("input",validarNombre ,false)
  nombres.addEventListener("input",validarNombre,false)
  correos.addEventListener("input", validarCorreo, false)}

function validarNombre(){
    if(lista[0] !==nombres || lista[1] !==nombres || lista[2] !==nombres || lista[3]=!!nombres)
      alert("nombre no existente")
}

function validarCorreo(){
  if(!correos.endsWith(".es"))
    alert(El correo debe acabar en .es);
}

Comment: Me refería a que editaras la pregunta. Ya lo he realizado, ahora tu pregunta recibirá más atención. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al llamar al método [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) te retornará un objeto de tipo [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element). Por lo que al intentar acceder al valor de las opciones del `dataList` como si de un `array` se tratara te lanzará un error.

La manera correcta de acceder a las opciones del `dataList` es:

```
var opciones = document.getElementById("personas").options;
```

Esto te devolverá un objeto con todas las opciones del `dataList` y este objeto en muchas cosas es parecido a un `array`, ya que puedes acceder a sus elementos utilizando índices. Observa cómo obtener el valor de la primera opción del `dataList`:

```
var valor_opcion1 = opciones[0].value;
```

Por lo tanto, lo único que debes hacer es recorrer las opciones del `dataList` para determinar si el texto introducido por el usuario se encuentra entre uno de sus valores. Una idea que se me ocurre es que mediante [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) crees un `array` con todos los valores como cadena y después en la función que verifica sólo verifiques si el texto introducido se encuentra o no dentro del `array`:

```js
var lista = document.getElementById("personas");
var nombres = document.getElementById("nombre");

//---Obtener un array con todos los valores de la lista
var listaArray = Array.prototype.map.call(lista.options, function(option) {
  return option.value;
});

nombres.addEventListener("input", validarNombre, false);

function validarNombre() {

  if (listaArray.indexOf(this.value) >= 0) {

    console.log("el nombre se encuentra en la lista");

  } else {

    console.log("el nombre no se encuentra en la lista");

  }

}
```

```html
<li>
  <datalist id="personas">
    <option value="alex" label="alex">
    <option value="juan" label="juan">
    <option value="ana" label="ana">
    <option value="Pedro" label="Pedro">
  </datalist>

  <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required placeholder="Escriba su nombre:" list="personas">
  <label> </label>
</li>
```

**Edición:** Otra solución que podrías aplicar es crear un objeto a modo de [hash map](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_hash) y verificar si la cadena introducida se encuentra entre una de las propiedades de dicho objeto:

```js
var lista = document.getElementById("personas");
var nombres = document.getElementById("nombre");

//---Obtener un hash map con todos los valores de la lista como propiedades con valor true
var listaHash = Array.prototype.reduce.call(lista.options, function(obj, option) {
  obj[option.value] = obj[option.value] || true;
  return obj;
}, {});

nombres.addEventListener("input", validarNombre, false);

function validarNombre() {

  if (listaHash[this.value]) {

    console.log("el nombre se encuentra en la lista");

  } else {

    console.log("el nombre no se encuentra en la lista");

  }

}
```

```html
<li>
  <datalist id="personas">
    <option value="alex" label="alex">
    <option value="juan" label="juan">
    <option value="ana" label="ana">
    <option value="Pedro" label="Pedro">
  </datalist>

  <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" required placeholder="Escriba su nombre:" list="personas">
  <label> </label>
</li>
```